# Spring Data autowiring multiple datasources fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, autowired

I have been hacking away at trying to get multiple mysql datasources into a Spring jpa application for what seems like forever. I have yet to find a good, working example online. Below are excerpts from an extremely stripped down app I'm making just to see if it is even possible in a vacuum to be able to autowire and query repositories for more than one MySQL db. No matter what annotations I sub in or out nothing changes, I always get the same error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here is my setup. Primary and Secondary beans and repos are in their own packages per the advice of several previously answered items.

first config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.download.integration.repositories.primary" })
public class PrimaryConfig{

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adaptor.setShowSql(false);
        adaptor.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adaptor.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return adaptor;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/primarydb");
        ds.setUsername("user");
        ds.setPassword("password");
        return ds;
    }

        @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
        public EntityManager primaryEntityManager() {
                return primaryEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        }

        @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")
        public EntityManagerFactory primaryEntityManagerFactory() {
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                lef.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
                lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
                lef.setPackagesToScan("com.download.domain.primary");
                lef.setPersistenceUnitName("primaryPersistenceUnit");
                lef.afterPropertiesSet();
                return lef.getObject();
        }

        @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
                return new JpaTransactionManager(primaryEntityManagerFactory());
        }

}
```

secondary config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.download.integration.repositories.secondary" })
public class SecondaryConfig{

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adaptor.setShowSql(false);
        adaptor.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adaptor.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return adaptor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/secondarydb");
        ds.setUsername("user");
        ds.setPassword("password");
        return ds;
    }

        @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManager")
        public EntityManager secondaryEntityManager() {
                return secondaryEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        }

        @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
        public EntityManagerFactory secondaryEntityManagerFactory() {
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                lef.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
                lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
                lef.setPackagesToScan("com.download.domain.secondary");
                lef.setPersistenceUnitName("secondaryPersistenceUnit");
                lef.afterPropertiesSet();
                return lef.getObject();
        }

        @Bean(name = "secondaryTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager() {
                return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEntityManagerFactory());
        }

}
```

primary datasource model:

```
@Entity
public class Primary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String word;
    private Double weight;
    private Date updated;
    private String sources;
```

...constructors, getters, setters

secondary datasource model:

```
@Entity
public class Secondary {

    @Id
    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private Double weight;
```

...constructors, getters, setters

And repositories (I have experiments with adding @Repository and seen no change)

```
public interface PrimaryRepository extends CrudRepository<Primary, Integer> {
}

public interface SecondaryRepository extends CrudRepository<Secondary, Integer> {
}
```

finally, the main class:

```
@ComponentScan("com.download")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import({PrimaryConfig.class, SecondaryConfig.class})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    PrimaryRepository primaryrepository;
    @Autowired
    SecondaryRepository secondaryrepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        search();

    }

    public void search(){
        primaryrepository.findAll();
        secondaryrepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Adding full stack trace per request:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.download.Application.main(Application.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 23 common frames omitted

2015-07-31 17:39:22.028  INFO 26516 --- [lication.main()] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-07-31 17:39:22.029  INFO 26516 --- [lication.main()] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/cora/multiDatasourceTest/src/main/resources, file:/Users/cora/multiDatasourceTest/src/main/resources, file:/Users/cora/multiDatasourceTest/target/classes/, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.5/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.0.CR3/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.0.CR3.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.7.2.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.2.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.23/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/hibernate-core-5.0.0.CR3.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.5/aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.2.2.Final/jandex-1.2.2.Final.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cora/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar]
2015-07-31 17:39:22.030  INFO 26516 --- [lication.main()] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-07-31 17:39:22.031 ERROR 26516 --- [lication.main()] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.download.Application.main(Application.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 23 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.download.Application.main(Application.java:32)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository com.download.Application.PrimaryRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.download.integration.repository.primary.PrimaryRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: if you're asking if I have a PrimaryRepositoryImpl class, I do not.

Comment: typo here, i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `@Import` and put `@EnableAutoConfiguration` without `exclude` field for simplicity.  Also, try adding `@Configuration` to your main class.

**EDIT:**

I've created a project with your classes and made if work after following changes:

1 `Application.java`

```
@ComponentScan("com.download")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  PrimaryRepository primaryrepository;
  @Autowired
  SecondaryRepository secondaryrepository;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    search();

  }

  public void search() {
    primaryrepository.findAll();
    secondaryrepository.findAll();
  }

}
```

2 `PrimaryConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager",
    basePackages = {"com.download.integration.repositories.primary"})
public class PrimaryConfig {

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adaptor.setShowSql(false);
    adaptor.setGenerateDdl(false);
    adaptor.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return adaptor;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
  public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/primarydb");
    ds.setUsername("user");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    return ds;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.download.domain.primary"});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

3 `SecondaryConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.download.integration.repositories.secondary"})
public class SecondaryConfig {

  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adaptor.setShowSql(false);
    adaptor.setGenerateDdl(false);
    adaptor.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return adaptor;
  }

  @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
  public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/secondarydb");
    ds.setUsername("user");
    ds.setPassword("password");
    return ds;
  }

  @Bean(name = "secondaryEntityManager")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.download.domain.secondary"});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(secondaryEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: those changes prompted a "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory" error ... i ran in to this a while back and never could resolve

Comment: i got past this and now back to initial bean autowiring error from before

Comment: Can you please put  the full stack trace of the error you mentioned in your post? Well, maybe the problem is Spring actually finds PrimaryRepository but couldn't initialize it. Creating EntityManagerFactory instances with names different than "entityManagerFactory" may cause the problem. You can try configuring LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean instead. Please check this example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: I added the full stacktrace. also i have a link to this on github if you want to see the whole enchilada for context

Answer (score 0):

My code exhibited the same issue, where it was ignoring secondary databases in a multiple database configuration and aways using the one annotated as primary. Found the problem cause by having @EnableJpaRepositories in one of controllers. After I removed the annotation, everything started working as expected.